# Cropping and Saving TIFF files in Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am new to python coding. I have been trying to crop a series of .tif images generated by X-Rays. Now, it crops successfully and shows the image generated but I cannot save them. Images when saved come out to be completely black. The line of code I am using is as follows:

```
    from PIL import Image
    import numpy
    startx = 421
    starty = 118
    stopx = 1182
    stopy = 336
    startfile = 1722
    stopfile = 1951
    for i in range(startfile,stopfile+1):
        image = Image.open("Filepath"+str(startfile)+".tif")
        cropped_image = image.crop((startx,starty,stopx,stopy))
        print("ipp"+str(startfile)+" cropped")
        image1 = cropped_image.rotate(180,0,1)
        image1.save("Filepath"+str(startfile),".tif")
        print("ipp"+str(startfile)+" saved")
        startfile = startfile + 1
        starty = starty + 3
        stopy = stopy + 3
```

Need Help!

Comment: If you dont have to stick to this solution, i was doing the same by creating a file cropper in CV and using python to call this executable. It is much faster and you can do it easily multithreaded.

Comment: I tried importing OpenCV 3.0.0 in Python. Turns out CV is not compatible with Python 3.4.

Comment: Try using the [`pillow` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow). It's a maintained fork of `PIL` and, if nothing else, you can submit a bug report if it still doesn't work.

Comment: i dont mean opencv python, opencv c++

Comment: I have used Pillow-2.8.1-cp34-none-win32.whl (md5) module...is there any other module i should use in Pillow. I am running a Win 8.1 OS on 64bit processor

Comment: I found the solution. just before save i converted the file to i presume 32 bit since the image was in 16 bit :
        image1.convert('L').save("Filepath"+str(startfile)+".tif")

Answer (score 2):

I think the error lies here:

```
image1.save("Filepath"+str(startfile),".tif")
```

The first argument should be the filename, including the extension. The second argument is optional, and gives a format. The filename you give, does not have an extension. This line should be:

```
image1.save("Filepath"+str(startfile)+".tif")
```

Comment: Thank you for replying... I did correct that and also convert('L') before saving it.. but it got truncated to 8bits to show the result.... else if i just save it, the code works with no error but the output file is not visible in Windows Photo Viewer but is visible in ImageJ